# Why does the ssh connection freeze when accessing gpio pins

Tags: pi-zero-w, wiringpi

What is the proper method to use when creating a blinking LED example using PI zero W

I connected the cathode to GPIO 37 and the anode to GND next I `ssh`ed into the pi and wrote this code

```
import wiringpi
wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio()
wiringpi.pinMode(37,1)
wiringpi.digitalWrite(37,1)
```

this code results in the ssh connection freezing and leaving me no other choice other than rebooting the pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio() says to use Broadcom GPIO numbering.
You are using GPIO 37 which is used by the Pi internals.

I suggest you only use GPIO available from the expansion header.

See https://pinout.xyz/

Answer (score 0):

You must use a resister to connect an LED to the GPIO pins of a Pi. Without a resistor you will draw too much current and either crash or damage the Pi.

Here I am using a 330 Ohm resistor with a blue LED connected to GPIO26 (physical pin 37). https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin37_gpio26

I suggest using the gpiozero library - it is simpler and has more functionality.

```
from gpiozero import LED
from signal import pause

led = LED(26)

led.blink()

pause()
```

https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#led

[image]